# Android Audience Network Ad doesn't show next Ad

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, facebook-audience-network

I have `RecyclerView`, where  every 14-th item  is a Facebook `Audience Network Ad`.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = 0;
    if (position % 14 == 0 && position != 0) viewType = 2;
    return viewType;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            return  new MainViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false));
        case 2:
            return new AdHolder((LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_test3, parent, false)));
    }
    return null;
}
```

The is as follows: every 14th element is the same. Here's `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FoodData foodData = foodDataList.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            MainViewHolder mainViewHolder = (MainViewHolder) holder;
            ...
            break;
        case 2:
            AdHolder adHolder = (AdHolder) holder;
            //System.out.println("ad hasH" + position);
            if (manager.isLoaded()) {
                NativeAd nativeAd;
                if (map.containsKey(position)) {
                    nativeAd = map.get(position);
                } else {
                    nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
                    map.put(position, nativeAd);
                }

                System.out.println(" Native Ad" + nativeAd.hashCode());
                System.out.println(" Native Ad.Title" + nativeAd.getAdTitle());

                adHolder.templateContainer.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Config.AD_HEIGHT_DP));
                adHolder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                adHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                adHolder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
                adHolder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(nativeAd.getAdIcon().getUrl())
                        .tag("resume_tag")
                        .into(adHolder.nativeAdIcon);

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(nativeAd.getAdCoverImage().getUrl())
                        .resize(width, ad_height)
                        .tag("resume_tag")
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.adholder2)
                        .into(adHolder.nativeAdMedia);

                System.out.println("url =" + nativeAd.getAdCoverImage().getUrl());

                if (adHolder.adChoicesView == null) {
                    adHolder.adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                    adHolder.adChoiceContainer.addView(adHolder.adChoicesView, 0);
                }
                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(holder.itemView);
            } else {
                adHolder.params = adHolder.templateContainer.getLayoutParams();
                adHolder.templateContainer.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

What I can't understand  is  when  I  check where I the same NativeAd `object`:

```
 System.out.println(" Native Ad" + nativeAd.hashCode());
 System.out.println(" Native Ad.Title" + nativeAd.getAdTitle());
```

I find, that  `hashCode`  of the NativeAd changes, but `title` (and other elements)  doesn't!

Hope  somebody we'll help me. Here's full code of `Adapter` https://gist.github.com/burnix/c1dd34dd896f5c6ddc6b2b8971908e28

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to post a sample project for checking the issue. Base on the adapter code only is not sufficient.

From the code, the short answer is the ad manager was not loaded properly.

The long answer is when ad manager is called with `manager.laodAds()`, the ads can be filled fully or partially, and checking `manager.isLoaded()` is not enough. The best practice is to set the `NativeAdsManager.Listener::onAdsLoaded()` to ensure all ads are loaded properly. It's also recommended to move `manager` from adapter to activity.

Notable point is each nativeAd only register once `registerViewForInteraction(View)`. This is not correct. Since the viewHolder will be different each time, to allow the nativeAd work properly, it has to unregister the view frist then register it again for the right view.

Another notable point is the manager only requested 3 native ads from beginning, and the code inside adapter is keeping calling `manager.nextNativeAd()` without check the valid number. This will cause continuous loop within the 3 ads if placements are more than 3. This may not be the best way to do base on revenue consideration.